# List name that have every items in MsSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

```
TableA
Name Items
  A  1
  A  2
  A  2
  A  3
  A  3
  B  1
  B  1
  B  2
  B  2
  C  1
  C  2
  C  2
  C  3

TableB
Items ItemsName
   1  One
   2  Two
   3  Three
```

I want to list

```
Name
A
C
```

Because A and C have every items in TableB. And B doesn't have 3.
I think I should use "NOT EXISTS" maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM TableB AS b
JOIN TableA as a ON b.Items = a.Items
GROUP BY a.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.Items) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Items) FROM TableB)
```

The query joins records of `TableB` with records of `TableA`. Using an `INNER JOIN` we can find matching records of `TableA`.

The `HAVING` clause checks whether the number of distinct `Items` values is equal to the population if `TableB`. Only `a.Name` values related to *all* `Items` values of `TableB` are returned.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce776/5)